Gophers in backyard removal asap?
We live in Utah and have a pocket gophers problem in our backyard. They are causing substantial damage to our lawn, we can't grow a garden because they eat everything, our fruit trees are dying due to them eating the roots. We don't want to use poison because we have a pet.
We have tried loud noises and vibrating posts which are not working. Please help!

What does local regulations permit?

smoke them out ...

I suppose the question here may be: .22LR or .17HMR?

Apparently you need more snakes and weasels, which eat them and can follow them down their holes.

You might get a good answer or two here, but sometimes the answer is simply, ‘call a professional’.

This would probably be better received over at Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange.

You can't get rid of them, you have to keep them out in the first place, or make your garden unattractive.
To keep them out either a wire fence around the perimeter of the area you want to protect, that extends 18 inches below ground or for a lawn you can lay wire mesh flat, across the entire lawn, just below the sod.  The latter doesn't work for beds or trees.
With gophers, making the garden unattractive is very hard.  Replacing the lawn with hardscape is about the only way.  Keeping a guard animal and training it to frighten the gophers is another.

Seconded here. One of my family members had to build hardscape with raised beds on top of it to finally stop their gopher and vole problem.

There are a few options, some you already considered. Others:

Fencing: Can be expensive and might not work anyway. If you go this route, to be more gofer proof you need to have some garden edging / root blocking sheets run a few inches deep under the fence. Even then they might find ways through it.

Trapping: This worked best in my area. Setup live-traps sized appropriately, check them regularly, release miles away. We had multiple families of groundhogs in the Northeast and my neighbor trapped and relocated lots of them, I think around ten were relocated, and that resolved our groundhog problem for the year (they are back one or two years later, need to do it again, but it seems like a humane option and multiple neighbors can team up to do it).

Hunting: Depending on local regulations and neighbors you might be able to hunt them using a smaller caliber rifle. Dogs could also assist. On farms that have pressure from creatures like groundhogs, squirrels etc., inviting small-game hunters and employing dogs can be effective and economical.

Repellents: There are some repellents that could work for specific plants and locations, but this is a piecemeal solution, might have similar problems as poisoning (less lethal but still offensive), and would need to be re-applied regularly (after heavy rains or after a few months time). Options include bloodmeal fertilizer, garlic, capscaicin, rotten eggs, castor oil, some other essential oils. You can lookup options online and there are even some companies making organic deer, gofer, rabbit, and squirrel repellents like this.


